# "The SSL certificate contains a common name (CN) that does not match the hostname." in VSTS Deployment

Tags: ssl, tfs, winrm, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am using VSTS to deploy to an Azure VM.  In my release definition, I receive the following error when trying to copy files over:

> The SSL certificate contains a common name (CN) that does not match
>   the hostname. For more information, see the
>   about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.To fix WinRM connection
>   related issues, select the 'Enable Copy Prerequisites' option in the
>   task. If set already, and the target Virtual Machines are backed by a
>   Load balancer, ensure Inbound NAT rules are configured for target port
>   (5986). Applicable only for ARM VMs. For more info please refer to
>   https://aka.ms/azurefilecopyreadme};]

I am not using a load balancer.  I noticed that the issue occurs whenever I add a DNS name label for my VM in the Azure portal (in the public IP settings).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The issue is not with the host file or the build agent, but rather the server certificate on the **TARGET** machine.  For me, I was using VSTS to deploy to an **Azure VM** when I encountered the issue, but the solution remains the same for **onsite** machines as well.

For an Azure VM deployment, the issue occurs when you create a VM without a **DNS Name Label** for your public IP, and then later add one (something like `example.centralus.cloudapp.azure.com`).  It can also occur if you change the DNS name label.

---

## Issue

You'll want to check how you're connecting to the machine.  Before, it was working just fine using the Azure VM IP address.  Now, VSTS started trying to use `example.centralus.cloudapp.azure.com:5986` since I had recently added a DNS name label.  We'll call this the **target machine address**.

On the **target** machine, open up PowerShell or Command Prompt as an administrator, and enter the command '`winrm e winrm/config/listener`'.  It should return two listeners, one for **HTTP** and another for **HTTPS** (if one is not listed for HTTPS, don't worry we'll add one later).  Pay particular attention to the **Hostname** for the HTTPS listener.  If this doesn't match the **target machine address** we found earlier, that is what is causing the error.  The **CertificateThumbprint** corresponds to a server certificate on the machine.

To view these certificates, from PowerShell or Command Prompt, type `mmc` and press enter.  Go to 'File' > 'Add/Remove Snap-in...'.  Select 'Certificates', and click **Add**.  In the dialog box, select 'Computer Account' and click **Next** then **Finish**.  Under 'Certificates' > 'Personal' > 'Certificates', you will see the certificate being used by the WinRM configuration.  Certificates here that are self-signed are considered **Test Certificates** because they are not backed by an official certificate authority.  We will need to create one that represents the **target machine address** you want to use.

You can also view certificates in IIS under '**Server Certificates**'.

---

## Solution

Make sure you know what address you want to use to connect to the machine.  This is the **target machine address**.

On the **target** machine, open PowerShell as an administrator.  Enter the following command.

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName WhateverTargetMachineAddressYouNeed -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My
```

This creates a new server certificate for your target address with a validity period of one year.

Next, we want to recreate the WinRM listener for HTTPS transport types to use the new certificate.  Open IIS and look at **Server Certificates** for your web server.  You should see the one you just created.  Right-click on it and select 'View...'.  In the **Details** tab, copy the **Thumbprint** for the certificate.  You can also do this from the mmc if you prefer.

Enter the following commands one at a time in PowerShell.

```
winrm delete winrm/config/listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTPS
```

Then:

```
winrm create winrm/config/listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTPS '@{Hostname="WhateverTargetMachineAddressYouNeed";CertificateThumbprint="TheThumbprintYouCopied";port="5986"}'
```

**Done!**  If you enter `winrm e winrm/config/listener` in PowerShell, you should now see the HTTPS transport using your new certificate.

If anything in your release definition or deployment scripts is using the old address (for me, the Azure VM IP address), be sure to update them to use the new **target machine address** (for me, the Azure VM DNS name label) WITH port number.  In VSTS, make sure you check the box for using a '**Test Certificate**'.  Good luck!

For more information, you can go here:

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/windows-azure/1289/configure-winrm-execute-powershell-remote-azure-with-arm

Comment: Had a similar issue while trying to connect to the machine deploying to: using the https hostname instead of the IP address fixed it for me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation!  Worked perfectly for my problem.

Comment: It is never too late

Comment: Is it possible to increase the expiration date of the certificate on Windows Server 2012?

Comment: There is a parameter for the `New-SelfSignedCertificate` cmdlet that allows you to add: `-NotAfter (Get-Date).AddMonths(6)` (for six months as an example)

Comment: For anyone else who gets **Error: Invalid use of command line. Type "winrm -?" for help**. when creating the listener, remove the single quotes around the config (Server 2019)

Comment: I received a "The SSL certificate is signed by an unknown certificate authority." when trying to create a New-PSSession to the server after following this.