# Connect to vm with run pwsh on target machine task and getting error "The SSL certificate contains a common name that does not match the hostname"

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-powershell

I am trying to connect to vm using run powershell on target machine task using classic editor to trigger a python code which needs to be downloaded from artifact on the target machine (here, vm).
I am getting an error " The SSL certificate contains a common name (CN) that does not match the hostname. "
I have tried to change settings in certificate snap-in but it still gave me same error.

Comment: Based on the error message, the issue occurs when you create a VM without a DNS Name Label for your public IP, and then later add one (something like example.centralus.cloudapp.azure.com). It can also occur if you change the DNS name label.

Comment: You can refer this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42538540/the-ssl-certificate-contains-a-common-name-cn-that-does-not-match-the-hostnam)or [MSDN forum discussion](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4dcc3a95-5191-4619-84f2-b1589744657d/the-ssl-certificate-contains-a-common-name-cn-that-does-not-match-the-hostname?forum=TFService) to resolve your issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @VenkateshDodda-MT & @srbrills Posting your suggestion as an answer to help other community members.

The **server certificate** on the TARGET system, not the **host file** or the **build agent**, is the problem.

The problem happens when you build an **Azure VM without a DNS Name Label** for your **public IP** and then add one afterwards (something like example.centralus.cloudapp.azure.com). It can also happen if the **DNS name label is changed.**

- You need to make  sure that, what address you want to use to connect to the machine. This is the  **target machine address**.

On the  **target**  machine, open PowerShell as an **administrator**. Enter the following command.

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName WhateverTargetMachineAddressYouNeed -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My
```

Enter the following commands one at a time in PowerShell.

```
winrm delete winrm/config/listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTPS
```

Then:

```
winrm create winrm/config/listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTPS '@{Hostname="WhateverTargetMachineAddressYouNeed";CertificateThumbprint="TheThumbprintYouCopied";port="5986"}'
```

- For more information please refer this [SO THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42538540/the-ssl-certificate-contains-a-common-name-cn-that-does-not-match-the-hostnam) & [*Configure WinRM to execute PowerShell Script on a remote Azure machine with ARM*](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/windows-azure/1289/configure-winrm-execute-powershell-remote-azure-with-arm)